# JavaScript Automatically decoding JSON sent by PHP via a HTML <div> data attribute?

Tags: javascript, php, html

I am using Google Charts to build a chart of some database data on my PHP CMS I am building. I can build the javascript code into the PHP but I would rather keep the Javascript and PHP as separate as possible. This involves me building the chart_data array in PHP and sending and grabbing it using JQuery in my scripts.js file. I used json_encode on the data prior to having it captured in my scripts.js file; however when it arrives in my scripts.js file. it has already been parsed back into an array of arrays. without using JSON.parse. Why is this happening automatically; and, is this a problem?

my chart.php file:

```
 $chart_data = [];
  $chart_row = [];

  $column_text = ['Data', 'All Posts', 'Active Posts', 'Draft Posts', 'Comments', 'Unapproved Comments', 'Users', 'Subscribers', 'Categories']; 
  $column_count = ['Count', $post_count, $active_post_count, $draft_post_count, $comment_count, $unapproved_comments_count, $user_count, $subscribers_count, $category_count];

  for ($i = 0; $i < count($column_text); $i++) {
    array_push( $chart_row, $column_text[$i], $column_count[$i] );
    array_push( $chart_data, $chart_row ); 
    $chart_row = [];
  }

  $chart_data_json = json_encode($chart_data);

  echo "<div id='chart_data' data-chart-data='{$chart_data_json}'></div>";
```

and my scripts.js file:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

  // GOOGLE CHART FUNCTIONALITY 
  var chartData = $('#chart_data').data('chart-data');

  google.charts.load('current', {'packages':['bar']});
  google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);

  function drawChart() {
    var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable(chartData);

    var options = {
      axisTitlesPosition: 'none',
      chart: {
        title: '',
        subtitle: '',
      }
    };

    var chart = new google.charts.Bar(document.getElementById('columnchart_material'));

    chart.draw(data, google.charts.Bar.convertOptions(options));
  }
});
```

Using this code everything is functioning properly. without A JSON.parse

Comment: It likely just calls the parse automatically because you're going to do it anyway. I can't see where you do the fetch of the server data, but jQuery would automatically parse JSON for you unless you explicitly pass a parameter to tell it not to.

Comment: If data attribute contains a valid json, than it will be converted - that is a bonus for you, not an issue. If you want to get the plain value or your attribute, than you can use [jQuery attr()](http://api.jquery.com/attr/) as `$('#chart_data').attr('data-chart-data')`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a feature of [`.data()`](https://api.jquery.com/data/#data-html5), the jQuery method:

> Every attempt is made to convert the attribute's string value to a JavaScript value (this includes booleans, numbers, objects, arrays, and null). A string is only converted to a number if doing so doesn't change its representation (for example, the string "100" is converted to the number 100, but "1E02" and "100.000" are left as strings because their numeric value of 100 serializes to "100"). When a string starts with '{' or '[', then `jQuery.parseJSON` is used to parse it; it must follow [valid JSON syntax](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON#Data_types.2C_syntax_and_example) *including quoted property names*. A string not parseable as a JavaScript value is not converted.

Note the exceptions for primitive values like 1E02 and 100.00: these are actually valid JSON, but are not parsed and left as strings. However, the method *does* convert "false", "true" and "null" to their JSON-parsed values.

Also a word of caution when generating such attribute content as HTML output: ampersands and less-than symbols should be written as HTML entities.